# media player classic - jump to point in video/audio programmatically

Tags: winapi, controls, media-player, autohotkey

In Media Player Classic I found a way to jump to a point in a video/audio programmatically, avoiding the `Go To...` box.
The jump distances are available at <kbd>Options</kbd> → <kbd>Tweaks</kbd>,
and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MPC-HC\MPC-HC\Settings`
(`JumpDistL`/`JumpDistM`/`JumpDistS`).

What I do is find the jump distances in the address space of Media Player Classic, and set the value of the large jump distance such
that if you applied it to the elapsed time you would get the desired time.

I then send a `WM_COMMAND` message with parameter `903`/`904` (all via AutoHotkey. I get the elapsed time by retrieving/parsing the contents of the <kbd>Edit</kbd> control.)

Because the jump is *relative* to the current point, it is imprecise,
and arrives within a second of the right time, but doesn't arrive
at exactly the same point each time.

Is there a more direct way of accomplishing this and if not,
would any Media Player Classic users/programmers
consider discussing on the forum, introducing new `WM_COMMAND` messages
that allow jump to point (in milliseconds),
or that retrieve the numerical values listed [here](http://localhost:13579/variables.html)
(`state`, `position`, `duration`, `volumelevel`, `muted`, `playbackrate`, `reloadtime`).
(The method found [here](http://localhost:13579/variables.html) is too slow to get the time accurately, and requires special options be set).

Comment: It's already implemented via WM_COPYDATA, see mpcapi.h in source code and [autoit example](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/85354-media-player-classic-homecinema-mpc-remote-api-via-wm_copydata/) which you can rip/convert to AHK or maybe even find an existing lib.

Comment: Due to the way video data is encoded it is unlikely that you can jump to an arbitrary position with millisecond precision. You cannot restart playback in between keyframes.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you disable the "fast seek" option (also in Tweaks)? This option makes MPC jump to keyframes instead of progress the video from nearest keyframe to the selected point in between keyframes

Comment: @wOxxOm Excellent response, much appreciated.
You are the author of AutoHotkey's InBuf are you not!
Which has been immensely useful to me.
And an expert in both AutoHotkey and AutoIt?
A pleasure to have you on my page.

Comment: @IInspectable Depending on the video and on the settings,
MPC allows you to jump to a specific keyframe or to jump points
over a minute apart. -- My issue was that `Go To...` would jump to a consistent point,
but would need a MsgBox to be dismissed, whereas
my workaround bypassed the MsgBox
but would not jump to the exact point that `Go To...` would.

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis Thank you for this, I found out within the
last few months, that disabling Fast Seek would solve
a problem with a video I had that would for example,
let you jump to 48:43 or 50:11 but not in-between.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is it possible to make an x64 version of InBuf (for this and for other scripts)? I have asked others and made some effort. Many thanks if you can help. --
InBuf function currently 32-bit only (machine code binary buffer searching) - AutoHotkey Community
https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=28393

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the message from wOxxOm, below the question,
I have been able to create this AutoHotkey script,
which solves my original problem:
to set the elapsed time in Media Player Classic programmatically,
directly, without using the `Go To...` box.

It also solves the problem of retrieving
information about the video.

The hotkeys are:
- <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> to start the MPC API,
- <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> to retrieve information,
- the number keys to jump partway through the video.

```
;==================================================

^q:: ;start MPC API
hWnd := A_ScriptHwnd+0
OnMessage(WM_COPYDATA:=74, "On_WM_COPYDATA")
;64-bit
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\MPC-HC64\mpc-hc64.exe" /slave %hWnd%
;32-bit
;Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\MPC-HC\mpc-hc.exe" /slave %hWnd%
Return

;==================================================

^w:: ;display information
Send(vMPCApiHWnd, 0xA0003004, "") ;CMD_GETCURRENTPOSITION := 0xA0003004

vElapsed := 19990101
vDuration := 19990101
vElapsed += vMPCApiCurrent, S
vDuration += vMPCApiDuration, S

if (vMPCApiCurrent >= 3600) OR (vMPCApiDuration >= 3600)
vFormat := "HH:mm:ss"
else
vFormat := "mm:ss"

FormatTime, vElapsed, %vElapsed%, %vFormat%
FormatTime, vDuration, %vDuration%, %vFormat%

SplitPath, vMPCApiPath, vName, vDir, vExt, vNameNoExt, vDrive

vText = ;continuation section
(
title: %vMPCApiTitle%
author: %vMPCApiAuthor%
description: %vMPCApiDesc%
name: %vName%
path: %vMPCApiPath%
elapsed: %vElapsed% (%vMPCApiCurrent%)
duration: %vDuration% (%vMPCApiDuration%)
)

MsgBox %vText%
Return

;==================================================

#IfWinActive, ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW
0:: ;skip to point
1::
2::
3::
4::
5::
6::
7::
8::
9::
vNum := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 1-1)
vElapsed2 := Round(vMPCApiDuration*(vNum/10))

Send(vMPCApiHWnd, 0xA0002000, "" vElapsed2) ;CMD_SETPOSITION := 0xA0002000
Return
#IfWinActive

;==================================================

On_WM_COPYDATA(wParam, lParam, msg, hwnd)
{
global vMPCApiHWnd
global vMPCApiTitle
global vMPCApiAuthor
global vMPCApiDesc
global vMPCApiPath
global vMPCApiDuration
global vMPCApiCurrent

dwData := NumGet(lParam+0, 0)
cbData := NumGet(lParam+A_PtrSize)
lpData := NumGet(lParam + 2*A_PtrSize)
lpData := StrGet(lpData)

if (dwData = 0x50000000) ;CMD_CONNECT := 0x50000000
{
vMPCApiHWnd := lpData
WinGetClass, vWinClass, ahk_id %vMPCApiHWnd%
if (vWinClass = "MediaPlayerClassicW")
MsgBox, , , MPC API on, 3
}

if (dwData = 0x50000003) ;CMD_NOWPLAYING := 0x50000003
{
StringSplit, lpData, lpData, |
vMPCApiTitle := lpData1
vMPCApiAuthor := lpData2
vMPCApiDesc := lpData3
vMPCApiPath := lpData4
vMPCApiDuration := lpData5
}

if (dwData = 0x50000007) ;CMD_CURRENTPOSITION := 0x50000007
vMPCApiCurrent := lpData

Return true
}

;==================================================

Send(Hwnd, dwData, lpData)
{
static WM_COPYDATA := 0x4a

VarSetCapacity(COPYDATASTRUCT, 3*A_PtrSize, 0)
cbData := (StrLen(lpData) + 1) * (A_IsUnicode ? 2 : 1)
NumPut(dwData, COPYDATASTRUCT, 0)
NumPut(cbData, COPYDATASTRUCT, A_PtrSize)
NumPut(&lpData, COPYDATASTRUCT, 2*A_PtrSize)

SendMessage, % WM_COPYDATA, % A_ScriptHwnd , &COPYDATASTRUCT,, % "ahk_id " Hwnd
return ErrorLevel == "FAIL" ? false : true
}

;==================================================

;USEFUL LINKS
;Sending Strings Via SendMessage - Ask for Help - AutoHotkey Community
;https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/98334-sending-strings-via-sendmessage/

;Media Player Classic - Homecinema MPC remote API (via WM_COPYDATA) - AutoIt Example Scripts - AutoIt Forums
;https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/85354-media-player-classic-homecinema-mpc-remote-api-via-wm_copydata/

;mpcapi.h
;https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeeb/mpc-be/master/src/apps/mplayerc/mpcapi.h

;winapi - media player classic - jump to point in video/audio programmatically - Stack Overflow
;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310778/media-player-classic-jump-to-point-in-video-audio-programmatically

;==================================================
```

USEFUL LINKS:

Sending Strings Via SendMessage - Ask for Help - AutoHotkey Community
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/98334-sending-strings-via-sendmessage/

Media Player Classic - Homecinema MPC remote API (via WM_COPYDATA) - AutoIt Example Scripts - AutoIt Forums
https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/85354-media-player-classic-homecinema-mpc-remote-api-via-wm_copydata/

mpcapi.h
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeeb/mpc-be/master/src/apps/mplayerc/mpcapi.h